# How can I check how many existing accounts are still active month over month? BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a task to determine how many employees have left their department each month. I have data for the total amount at the beginning, but I want to gauge how many are leaving each month and determine the % drop

**Current table**

| Department | StartingMonth | NumberOfEmployees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marketing | 2022-06-01 | 550 |
| Finance | 2022-12-01 | 300 |

SELECT Department, StartingMonth, COUNT(EmployeeID)

FROM Employee

GROUP BY Department, StartingMonth

What I want to achieve, if using Marketing as an example. Of those 550 employees that were active/present in 2022-06-01 when the department started, for the next month and following months up until today, how many of them are still active?

To determine if the employee has left or not, use EmployeeCloseDate. If EmployeeCloseDate is NULL then they are active, if NOT NULL then they have left their job.

I am stuck on working out a LOOP or WHILE to use the following 'business logic':

1. COUNT(EmployeeID) - GROUP BY Department, StartingMonth
2. COUNT(EmployeeID) - GROUP BY Department, (StartingMonth + 1 month), WHERE EmployeeCloseDate IS NULL
3. COUNT(EmployeeID) - GROUP BY Department, (StartingMonth + 2 month), WHERE EmployeeCloseDate IS NULL

**Desired table**

| Department | StartingMonth | NEW LOOPED MONTH | NumberOfEmployees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marketing | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-01 | 550 |
| Marketing | 2022-06-01 | 2022-07-01 | 535 |
| Marketing | 2022-06-01 | 2022-08-01 | 500 |
| Marketing | 2022-06-01 | 2022-09-01 | 487 |
| Marketing | 2022-06-01 | 2022-10-01 | 486 |
| Marketing | 2022-06-01 | 2022-11-01 | 481 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| Finance | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-01 | 300 |
| Finance | 2022-12-01 | 2023-01-01 | 300 |
| Finance | 2022-12-01 | 2023-02-01 | 280 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |

And I want to the Month to be analysed to be up until the current month 2023-06-01 / 2023-07-01. I am using Google BigQuery SQL.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the table definition, and sample data, for the table that holds the information about employees. Are you only interested in employees who leave the department, not those who join?

Comment: Yes I am only interested in who leaves the department.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? I would like to know what employee data looks like, for example, StartingMonth and EmployeeCloseDate

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have employees start and end dates you may create two data arrays:

1. StartingMonth
2. NEWLOOPEDMONTH

Then join them back with the employees table and filter those employees that have been employed at the StartingMonth and also at NEWLOOPEDMONTH.

```
WITH employees AS (
SELECT 'Marketing' as Department, DATE '2023-01-13' as EmployeeStartDate, DATE '2023-04-02' as EmployeeCloseDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'Marketing' as Department, DATE '2023-02-23' as EmployeeStartDate, NULL              as EmployeeCloseDate
)
SELECT Department, StartingMonth, NEWLOOPEDMONTH, count(1) as NumberOfEmployees
from employees
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
  DATE_TRUNC(EmployeeStartDate, month),
  DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, month),
  INTERVAL 1 month)) as StartingMonth
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
  DATE_TRUNC(EmployeeStartDate, month),
  DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, month),
  INTERVAL 1 month)) as NEWLOOPEDMONTH
WHERE EmployeeStartDate <= StartingMonth
  and (StartingMonth    <= EmployeeCloseDate or EmployeeCloseDate is NULL)
  and StartingMonth     <= NEWLOOPEDMONTH
  and (NEWLOOPEDMONTH    <= EmployeeCloseDate or EmployeeCloseDate is NULL)
GROUP BY Department, StartingMonth, NEWLOOPEDMONTH
ORDER BY Department, StartingMonth, NEWLOOPEDMONTH
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate the SQL query. A few tweaks however, the Employee Start date is not relevant e.g. I just want a count of employees who are not closed each month. Going through each New Looped Month, how many of the original Count of employees on the starting month, are still active

Comment: It feels like it is impossible to get the result you want without the employees start date. The sample table at the top of your question does not have enough data to make the calculations you need. Because it does not have the number of employees that left the department as well the number of new employees. You need to have more detailed data on every employee like the one I put at the begging of my query.